# apache rewritemap not working URL does not translate

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewritemap

I cannot get my rewrite map to work. I have read a lot of pages on this and yet can't figure out how.

I have the following in my httpd.conf and took an apache restart

```
RewriteMap ErrorMap txt:/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/1/techencl/site.com/vb2xf.map
```

The rewrite map has the following entry (edited after the tip in the first reply)

```
corner/lock-unlock-140859.html http://www.site.com/com/ts/lock-unlock.70898/
```

The .htaccess in the root directory has the following entry

```
RewriteCond ${ErrorMap:$1|NOT_FOUND} !NOT_FOUND
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ${ErrorMap:$1|$1} [R=301]
```

Edit: Just posting my current .htaccess file contents for reference

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule [^/]+/.+-([\d]+)/p([\d]+)/ showthread.php?t=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule [^/]+/.+-([\d]+)/ showthread.php?t=$1 [NC,L]


Options +FollowSymlinks
rewritecond %{http_host} ^domain.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [r=301,nc] 

RewriteCond ${ErrorMap:$1|NOT_FOUND} !NOT_FOUND
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ${ErrorMap:$1|$1} [R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do in your rewrite rule?

Comment: I am trying to point all old URLs to their corresponding new URL. There will be around 10K of these.

Answer (score 0):

When you call the map:

```
${ErrorMap:$1
```

The `$1` is *never* going to have `http://www.site.com/` in it. It will only have this part:

```
corner/lock-unlock-140859.html
```

That means in your map, you need to make it look like this:

```
corner/lock-unlock-140859.html http://www.site.com/com/ts/lock-unlock.70898/
```

Comment: I have tried it with the following but it still does not work. "_corner/lock-unlock-140859.html_" "_lock-unlock-140859_"